# how to integrate Assently api for e-signature transaction in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, api, payment

In my wp project, I am using [Assently](https://assently.zendesk.com) for e-signature implementation. Though I have an account and created a pdf form file to be filled by the user I just am not able to proceed a bit. I am finding documentation not clear.
Also, I am not clear about what needs to be done so that the user will be shown form to process the transaction.

So, any help/suggestions to proceed forward is appreciated.

I have tried the following based on [assently-laravel](https://github.com/eklundkristoffer/assently-laravel). But it's asking me to login. What is an error here?
Code:

```
define('ASSENTLY_DEBUG', true);
define('ASSENTLY_KEY', 'key');
define('ASSENTLY_SECRET', 'secret-generated');

include_once('assently/Assently.php');
$assently = new Assently();
$assently->authenticate(ASSENTLY_KEY, ASSENTLY_SECRET);

$url = 'https://test.assently.com/api/v2/createcasefromtemplate';
$default = array(
    'Id' => '5a0e0869-' . rand(1111, 9999) . '-4b79-' . rand(1111, 9999) . '-466ea5cca5ce'
);
$data = array(
    'auth' => $assently->auth(),
    'templateId'    => '0e004e2b-b192-4ce2-8f47-d7a4576d7df6',
    'newCaseId'     => '5a0e0869-' . rand(1111, 9999) . '-4b79-' . rand(1111, 9999) . '-466ea5cca5ce',
    'agentUsername' => ''
);

$data = array(
    'json' => $data
);
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
die;
```

Comment: https://test.assently.com/api#communication What is unclear?

Comment: @Stefan I am not able to understand how to show pdf fillable form on click and then complete the whole transaction.

Comment: @Stefan can you provide some codes on how to do it or guide me here.

Comment: I think it's best to ask a new question and provide some more details. If you want to know how to show a form based on on-click, you should start there. It's good to know that I don't know anything about `Assently` ;-)

Comment: you are not sending the authentication in your request. You authenticated but no authentication sent in your request. check it once

Comment: try removing auth from top data array and put it with json data array. $data = array(
        'json' => $data,
        'auth' => $assently->auth()
    );

Comment: @RKJ no it's not working :(

Answer (score 1):

**create this class inside assently folder**

```
use Assently\AssentlyCase;
use Exception;

class  CustomAssentlyCase extends AssentlyCase 
{
    public function createFromTemplate($data)
    {
        $default = [
            'newCaseId' => '5a0e0869-'.rand(1111, 9999).'-4b79-'.rand(1111, 9999).'-466ea5cca5ce'
        ];

        $json = array_merge($default, $data);

        try{
            $response = $this->client->post($this->url('createcasefromtemplate'), [
                'auth' => $this->assently->auth(),
                'json' => $json
            ]);

        }catch(Exception $e){
            print_r($e->getMessage());
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

**Use**

```
define('ASSENTLY_DEBUG', true);
define('ASSENTLY_KEY', 'key');
define('ASSENTLY_SECRET', 'secret-generated');

include_once('assently/Assently.php');
include_once('assently/CustomAssentlyCase.php');
$assently = new Assently();
$assently->authenticate(ASSENTLY_KEY, ASSENTLY_SECRET);

$data = array(
    'templateId' => '0e004e2b-b192-4ce2-8f47-d7a4576d7df6',
    'newCaseId' => '5a0e0869-'.rand(1111, 9999).'-4b79-'.rand(1111, 9999).'-466ea5cca5ce',
    'agentUsername' => 'agentUsername' // PUT your agent username here it is required
);

$customAssentlyCase = new CustomAssentlyCase($assently);
$result = $customAssentlyCase->createFromTemplate($data);
print_r($result);
```

Try this, though not tested but should work. Good luck.